# ¿Manejo de "Enum" en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando algo en **JS** y necesito ordenar datos como variables estáticas en, *recorde* una  forma de hacer esto en java con el **Enum**, la cosa por lo que investigue es que no existen los enum en js (?), asi que intente crear un objeto

```
var baseValue = {
  kb = 1024.0,
  mb = 1048576,
  gb = 1099511627776
};
```

(cabe aclarar que no he trabajado mucho esto en **JS**)

Intento obtener uno de los valores así

```
alert(baseValue.kb);
```

pero me da el error **Invalid shorthand property initializer**

Comment: Estás declarando mal el objeto. La clave va seguido de dos puntos (`:`).

Comment: @Guz te refieres a que use : en ves de = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo en realidad es definiendo un objeto con propiedades y sintaxis para especificar las propiedades en la definición del objeto en javascript es con `:` no con `=`:

```js
var baseValue = {
  kb : 1024.0,
  mb : 1048576,
  gb : 1099511627776
};

console.log(baseValue.kb);
```

Comment: ya veo gracias Einer y @Guz por aclarlo